# Update EditText in ListView using TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, android-listview, textwatcher

first of all here is some code that I have written to try something out:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unit, parent, false);
        final TextView unitName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.unit_name);
        final EditText unitValue = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.unit_value);

        if(units.get(position).getView() == 1) {
            unitName.setText(units.get(position).getUnitName());
            unitValue.setText("0.00");
        } else {
            unitName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            unitValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        unitValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //nothing here
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                HashMap<String, Double> conversionFactors = new HashMap<String, Double>();
                //CONVERTER CLASS
                Converter converter = new Converter(type, unitName.getText().toString(), unitValue.getText().toString());
                //CONVERT METHOD
                conversionFactors = converter.convert();
                //UPDATE ALL OF THE UNITVALUES IN THEIR CURRENT ORDER
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //nothing here
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
```

I have a `HashMap` where the keys are the `TextView` objects in the layout, so I am going to go through them and update their corresponding `EditText` objects, using the corresponding values in the `HashMap`.

It is going to happen in the `onTextChanged` method, but the problem is my understanding. Since I already have the view instantiated is there a way that I can just iterate through all of the `EditText` objects and update them? or shall I just update my `ArrayAdapter`? not really sure where to go with it next...Would really appreciate some insight.

Comment: Update your adapter. Thats the better one..

Comment: @Sripathi thank you, I go ahead with updating the adapter and see how it works out for me. Thank you. Although, the ArrayAdapter only contains the list of Strings that populate the TextView objects in the view, I am trying to update the EditText objects that correspond to them, so I don't see how updating the ArrayAdapter is going to be of much use...

Comment: If you update the objects of the edittext, then you need to notify the adapter to make the changes in the adapter. So its a direct way to update the adapter..

Comment: @Sripathi ok I see, I go ahead with that then.